# How do I change the text displayed on a website?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is change one word of text on my webpage to run through a list of words.

ie:

```
<p>My favorite hobby is <u>fishing</u>!</p>
```

Where "fishing" would change after about 2 secs to the next word of a list of hobbies.

The closest example I've found is this

```
<div id="welcome">
<h3>Welcome, welcome, welcome!</h3>
<h3>Hang around a bit (for a surprise).</h3>
</div>
```

```
function ChangeIt() {
    var newcontent = '
    <h1><a href="page.html">Click here</a> ' +
    'for a web page with more of the same.</h1>';
    WriteContentIntoID("welcome",newcontent);
}
setTimeout("ChangeIt()",20000);
```

But I can't get it to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something simple using `setInterval()`:

```
    <p>My favorite hobby is <span id="ch">fishing</span>!</p>

    <script>
    var activities = ['eating', 'burping','coding'];
    var i=0;

    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("ch").innerHTML = activities[i];

       if (i < activities.length-1) {
         i++;
       } else {
        i=0;
       }

   }, 1000);
   </script>
```

[FIDDLE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cstd6LLd/)

EDIT: changed to make it loop forever.

Comment: That works perfect except once it gets to the end of the variables I want it to just repeat.

Comment: Now it's perfect! Thank you so much. Wish I'd have asked hrs ago LOL!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<p>My favorite hobby is <u>fishing</u>!</p>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getnewword(){
   return "me";// fix this section with getting new word!
}
function ChangeIt() {
   $("p u").html(getnewword());
   setTimeout("ChangeIt()",2000);
}
setTimeout("ChangeIt()",2000);
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Programming is cool. You should try with some beginner JavaScript tutorials like http://www.w3schools.com/js/.

You must encapsulate your script with script tag and you must use selectors (like document.getElementById).

This is the full code:

```
<div id="welcome">
<h3>Welcome, welcome, welcome!</h3>
<h3 id="hobby">Hang around a bit (for a surprise).</h3>
</div>
<script>
// we start with 0
var currentHobby = 0;

function ChangeIt() {
    // hobbies array
    var hobbies = ["fishing", "eating", "drinking", "programming"]; 

    // we save the current hobby in hobbyString and increment the currentHobby number
    var hobbyString = hobbies[currentHobby];
    currentHobby++;

    // if the currentHobby number is too big, we start with 0 again
    if(currentHobby >= hobbies.length) {
        currentHobby = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("hobby").innerHTML = "My favourite hobby is " + hobbyString;
}
setInterval("ChangeIt()",2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML PART

```
I am going to <span id="changingtext">InitialWord</span>
```

Javascript Part - You Need JQuery and call the following on `onLoad`

```
var texts = ["France", "Italy", "Ireland", "Wales"];
var count = 0;
function updateval() {
    $("#changingtext").text(texts[count]);
    count < 4 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(updateval, 2000);
```

Working JS Fiddle Link [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/anmtwutt/)

Click on the Javascript setting button on JsFiddle to check the settings put in use.